# Typo3, merging data from multiple database tables in one SysFolder-view

Tags: database, typo3

I am getting in backend of Typo3 a list of the entries from database table "Books" via SysFolder. I can make new books, edit books etc..

I have also a database table "Extrainformation" where I would like that will come the extra information about the book. In table "Extrainformation" there is a key "Book_id" as a connector between the tables.

What I am trying to get is that when I make a new record via this SysFolder I would like to get some of the fields saved in the different table.

Like when I have input fields:

- Bookname
- Book description
- Book Publishdate
- Extrafield1
- Extrafield2

I would like that infos about Bookname, Book description and Book Publishdate would be saved in the table "Books" and infos about Extrafield1 and Extrafield2 would be saved in "Extrainformation" table. (And then when I edit a book it should bring the data in to the form from these two tables)

Has someone made something like this before? Is there some easy way to combine databaseinformation from multiple tables via SysFolder? When there is no "easy" way, does someone know where would it be possible to "hack" (saving data in database / getting data from database) so that it would be possible to merge the data in one form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for "Inline relational record editing" [IRRE](http://wiki.typo3.org/wiki/Inline_Relational_Record_Editing).

BTW, there is nothing special about folders in the pagetree. Technically there is no difference to "normal" pages, except that they will not be rendered in frontend.

Comment: Thanks, that have helped me further.